# Nuevo Data Frame a partir de columnas determinadas

Tags: r, dataframe, rstudio

Tengo un data frame con 34 variables (`datosNum`) y quiero crear un data frame nuevo aparte (`datosNumSubgrupo`) que contenga variables determinadas de `datosNum`, sin nigún tipo de filtrado o criterio especial, sino variables que yo quiero que esten incluidas en el nuevo data frame a 'dedo' y que conserven su forma (osea, que el nuevo data frame tenga esas mismas columnas, separadas, como en el data frame original)

Si quiero que, por ejemplo, mi nuevo data frame contenga las variables `datosNum$MS`, `datosNum$Frontage` y `datosNum$LowQual` qué debería hacer? Para que luego, a la hora de hacer boxplots, los pueda hacer por subgrupos (los nuevos dataframes) y mostrarlos en un mismo gráfico:

`par(mfrow=c(1,1))`
`boxplot(datosNumSubgrupo)`

**** Si, que el nuevo data frame conserve el mismo número de observaciones/filas
Muchas gracias!

Comment: Es decir, quieres un nuevo `data.frame` con la misma cantidad de filas/observaciones, pero solo con ciertas variables/columnas?

Comment: ¡Si! Un nuevo data frame con la misma cantidad de observaciones/filas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La selección de variables/columnas de un `data.frame` puede hacerse con R base, de múltiples maneras, vamos a partir, a modo de ejemplo, del clásico `mtcars`

#### Mediante un vector numérico

Simplemente hay que definir un vector numérico, con los números de columnas a seleccionar

```
new <- mtcars[, c(1,2,3)]  # Seleccionamos 
new <- mtcars[, 1:5]       # Columna 1 a 5
new <- mtcars[, c(1:5, 7)] # La 1 a la 5 y la 7
new <- mtcars[, c(1,2,1)]  # Podemos repetir columnas: la 1, la 2 y la 1 nuevamente
```

#### Mediante un vector de lógicos

Podemos generar un vector de valores lógicos `TRUE` o `FALSE` para elegir las columnas deseadas

```
new <- mtcars[, c(TRUE, FALSE)] # Elegimos una columna si otra no con reciclado
new <- mtcars[, c(T, T, F, F, F, F, T, F, F, F, T)]
```

#### Mediante un vector de caracteres

Simplemente, se trata de la selección mediante el nombre de las columnas

```
new <- mtcars[, c("mpg", "cyl")] #Seleccionamos directamente por nombre de columna
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar con

```
datosNumSubgrupo<-datosNum[, c("MS","Frontage","LowQual")]
```

Comment: Esto no proporciona una respuesta a la pregunta. Para criticar o pedir aclaración a un autor, deja un comentario debajo de su publicación. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/239564)

Comment: No proporciona una respuesta? Es justo lo que pide